# Unifi pro switch without controller

Tags: switch, ubiquiti

We have a UniFi Switch Pro 48 PoE and we want to use it without a unifi controller but when we connect to the switch and change the configuration it is not saved, after a reboot the configuration is restored to default

Enter command for save configuration in cli

write memory:

```shell
copy flash:running-config nvram:startup-config
```

in shell mode:

```shell
save
```