# Persisting Ubiquiti switch settings without UniFi controller

Tags: switch

I have a [UniFi Industrial Switch](https://dl.ubnt.com/ds/usw-industrial), without any associated/available UniFi controller.
(Referred to on the Ubiquiti site as USW-Industrial, purchased because it offers a total 430W PoE++ power budget PoE on 8 ports.)

To get to its CLI:

1. Plug a port (any port, I've tried 1-8) into a network that offers DHCP. The MAC address on this switch starts with `24:5a:4c`.
2. Log in to the router over SSH; my network is very simple so `ssh -o HostKeyAlgorithms=ssh-rsa,ssh-dss ubnt@[ip-address]` with password `ubnt` works.
3. Once it gives you a `Welcome to UniFi USW-IND-8P-450!` message:

   ```
   UBNT-US.v4.0.49# icli
   UBNT# show running-config
   ```

   This dumps the current config, so you can confirm the changes you made were applied.
4. Make the actual changes you want. In my case, I enable VLANs + jumbo packets:

   ```
   configure terminal

   # repeat for interfaces 1-10
   interface GigabitEthernet 1/1
   switchport mode trunk
   mtu 9000

   exit
   ```

Now that the switch is working the way I want, I try to save the configuration to flash:

```
UBNT# copy running-config startup-config
Building configuration...
% Saving 2592 bytes to flash:startup-config
```

However, the configuration isn't saved. [This SO question](https://superuser.com/q/1714199/) suggests `copy flash:running-config nvram:startup-config`, but that doesn't persist across reboots/power loss either.

How do I save this configuration correctly?